# How can I with regex in javascript find a string between two other strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript I have the string of the following format:

```
var string = "directory/filename.extension";
```

and I want to retrieve the substring `filename`. I.e from the string `images/panda.jpg` I want to extract just `panda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string on these characters if it's always this consistent.

```
var r = 'images/panda.jpg'.split(/[/.]/)[1]
console.log(r) //=> "panda"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
> var s = "directory/filename.extension";
undefined
> s.match(/[^.\/]+(?=\.)/)
[ 'filename',
  index: 10,
  input: 'directory/filename.extension' ]
> s.match(/[^.\/]+(?=\.)/)[0]
'filename'
> "images/panda.jpg".match(/[^.\/]+(?=\.)/)[0]
'panda'
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var myRe = /\/([^.]+)./;
var result = myRe.exec("images/panda.jpg")[1];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = string.match(/.+?\/(.+?)\..+/);
var filename = result[1];
```

Hope this helps.